# How to use Redshift DATEDIFF?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

Im trying to add a date difference calculation to a Redshift SQL query:

```
SELECT 
   client,
   session,
   person_id,
   min(event_start) as "session_start",
   max(event_finish) as "session_finish",
   sum (case when event_type = 'execute-query-action-1'  then 1 else 0 end) as "Type1 reports run" ,
   sum (case when event_type = 'execute-query-action-2'  then 1 else 0 end) as "Type 2 reports run" ,
   DATEDIFF(MINUTE,session_start,session_finish) as "session_duration_minutes"
FROM usage_log
group by client,person_Id,session
```

... and I'm getting an error:

> function pg_catalog.date_diff("unknown", timestamp with time zone, timestamp with time zone) does not exist HINT: No function matches the given name and argument types. You may need to add explicit type casts.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 8):

The [DATEDIFF Function](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html) is documented as:

```
DATEDIFF ( datepart, {date|timestamp}, {date|timestamp} )
```

Thus, it can either take a **date** or a **timestamp**.

Your query is passing a **timestamp with time zone**, hence the error.

Therefore, you could use:

```
DATEDIFF(MINUTE, session_start::timestamp, session_finish::timestamp)
```

Answer (score 0):

Solution without `datediff`:

```
select 
    (
        cast(extract(epoch from to_timestamp(min(event_start), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS')) as integer) -
        cast(extract(epoch from to_timestamp(max(event_finish), 'YYYY-MM-DD HH24:MI:SS') ) as integer)
    ) / 60 as session_duration_minutes
FROM usage_log
```

The solution converts the timestamps to [unix epoch](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time), subtracts and truncates to floor(minutes).